# How to remove all rows of a datframe column that contain a question mark instead of occupation

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

This is my attempt:

```
df['occupation']= df['occupation'].str.replace('?',  '')

df.dropna(subset=['occupation'], inplace=True)
```

but it is not working, How do i remove all of the rows of the occupation column that i read from a csv file that contain a ? rather than an occupation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up the white space and use an 'unselect' filter:

```
import pandas as pd
bugs = ['grasshopper','cricket','ant','spider']
fruit = ['lemon','komquat','watermelon','apple']
squashed = ['  ?   ','Yes','No','Eww']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(bugs,fruit,squashed)), columns = ['Bugs','Fruit','Squashed'])
print(df.head())
```

[image]

```
df = df[df['Squashed'].apply(lambda x: x.strip()) != '?']
print('after stripping white space and after unselect')
print(df.head())
```

[image]

**Why**

The dataframe method .dropna() won't detect blanks (ie '') but will look for Nan or NaT or None.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

However, using .replace() to set the value to missing won't work because .replace() requires the type to match and None doesn't match any type you'll have in a column already.

Better to clean up the white space (which is the simple case) using lambda on each entry to apply the string transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading the csv with `pd.read_csv()`, you can pass `na_values`.

```
# to treat '?' as NaN in all columns:
pd.read_csv(fname, na_values='?')

# to treat '?' as NaN in just the occupation column:
pd.read_csv(fname, na_values={'occupation': '?'})
```

Then, you can `dropna` or `fillna('')` on that column as you see fit.

Comment: Hi this did not work the ? is still there

Comment: 26              Private
27                    ?
28              Private

Comment: The fields in the csv must have '?' only, no whitespace or other characters. Additionally, the name 'occupation' must match the column header.

Comment: occupation does match but how do i check if the rows that have ? have no white space?

Comment: I have found out that there is white spaces in the column how would i remove the white spaces?

Comment: If the whitespace is consistent, you can change the na_value specified to `"? "`, or even `["?", "? "]`. If it's not, then you're probably better off using the approach in your question but with a `strip` thrown in: `df['occupation'].str.strip().replace('?', '')`

Comment: @JohnJohnson, see my response above ..........
df  = df[df['Squashed'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())]

Will remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
df = df[df.occupation != "?"]
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: if you use this code `df['occupation']= df['occupation'].str.replace('?',  '')`, it will not work. Read csv again and use this again: `df = df[df["occupation"] != "?"]`

Comment: it didnt work because the cells that have a ? also have a ton of whitespace